# What fundamental force is at play in electron degeneracy pressure?

Tags: forces, white-dwarfs

For example 2 electrons repel each other because they experience electromagnetic force, matter particles attract each other because they exert gravitational force on each other, fusion is possible because of overcoming coulomb force etc, now my question is what force is pushing the electrons apart under immerse gravitational force such as white dwarf star? Pauli exclusion principle is not a force unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: It should be electromagnetic in nature though treatment must be quantum electrodynamics. Let us wait for a detailed answer

Comment: Fusion is what happens when particles come so close together that the strong force is within range (length scale of nucleii about 10^-13m). This generally involves overcoming the coulomb force, and gravity is negligile. Also, electrons don't fuse together. They can fuse with protons, but not other electrons.

Comment: Pauli principle is not a force but it shows up as being responsible for a pressure (and so a force). Even classically non-interacting particles at finite temperatures exert a pressure (the ideal gas). Quantum mechanically this pressure can show up also at zero temperature.

Comment: @Icv: my thought is the atom can only have max 2 electrons of spin up and down in the first orbital that the 3rd electron is "push" out to form second orbital... hence this is the pressure coming from the quantum mechanical effect, did i finally gasp the concept right?

Comment: Being not allowed to answer here, I make known that I posted my answer to the quoted 2012 question.